# Extend wagtail page visibility and add subscription plans

Tags: django, permissions, subscription, wagtail

I'm creating a website with wagtail where users can decide to buy a subscription plan.

Each subscription should allow access to a page on the site. For example, "only users in the premium plan can read the news."

The subscription must have an "expiry date".

At the moment the visibility can be blocked to users in a specific group (which can be managed as a subscription) but I don't know how to manage the expiration date and it doesn't seem to be a particularly elegant solution for my problem.

I haven't found anything to create a custom model user_group with an expiry_date field.

I would like to know how a situation like this should usually be handled and if it is possible to add another entry in the visibility section, for example: "private, accessible to users in specific subscriptions".

Answer (score 0):

Create your own middleware to check whether the subscription has expired and then remove the user from the group if the subscription is expired:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Where would you put the expiry_date field? are you imagining two different objects for group and subscription? In this case the editor should never use the standard way of setting visibility on the page but He should go inside the "AdminModel" Subscription...Is it  right?

Comment: I think you would need to put the expiration_date field on the Subscription model.  The Group model is built into Wagtail.  You can still set the visibility of the page in the Wagtail admin.  Just remove the subscriber from the Group in your middleware if the subscription is expired.